# How to bind the response data from my post method controller in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Given the Controller View and JS how do you bind the JSON data returned from a post action controller.Is this possible.

**Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PBHEP(string PC,string FC)
    {
     /some data calculations
       Output output = new Output() { CIR = CIR_, Recharge = Recharge_, GW_Withdrawal= GW_Withdrawal_ };
        return Json(output);
    }
```

**JS**

```
self.submit_conditions = function () {

    var PC_data = ko.toJSON(self.present_conditions());
    var FC_data = ko.toJSON(self.future_conditions());

    $.post("/Home/PBHEP", { "PC": PC_data, "FC": FC_data }, function (data) { alert((data));},'json');
}
```

After this when the controller returns the Json data "output" I see that in my dev tools I have Response from the POST in my network as **{"CIR":8.31779,"Recharge":4.28381,"GW_Withdrawal":32.27184}**
How Do I het this in my JS and later use it to bind as text on my UI.

Thank you in Advance!

Comment: You can use the data returned to bind to your UI element..  You can access the data returned as  data.CIR , data.Recharge to get the respective value and later bind them to your UI element .

Comment: If possible can you share a link with example on how to bind this data to a text in UI.I am currently using knockout JS which i am new to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your model has these output elements defined some where...

```
function vm(){
    var self = this;
    self.CIR = ko.observable();
    self.Recharge = ko.observable();
    self.GW_Withdrawl = ko.observable();
    //remaining stuff

    self.submit_conditions = function(){
        //usual stuff
        $.post(svcUrl, data, function(data){
            self.CIR(data.CIR);
            self.Recharge(data.Recharge);
            self.GW_Withdrawl(data.GW_Withdrawl);
        });
    };
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Now bind this as you would normally, for e.g.

```
<label>Recharge:</label><label data-bind="text: Recharge"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess if you are using ViewModels, you can create the same viewmodel on knockout and asp.net mvc, and make bind of the data normally.

On your controller:

```
var model = new YourViewModel();
// fill data to return
return Json(model);
```

On return to javascript you can use [knockout mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)